# retrieve multiple checked values from gridview C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I want to retrieve multiple checked values(id's) from asp:checkbox in my gridview. With the selected records, i want to do a delete function with nhibernate. The problem is that im getting only one value(id) from the gridview, even if i select multiple records. My goal is to delete the checked items in the gridview. My code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="labelID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Accountant") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDelete" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                    oncheckedchanged="cbDelete_CheckedChanged" /> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

This one works. The list gets all the values from the checked items.

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      List<int> lstE = new List<int>();
      foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in gvAccountants.Rows)
      {
            if (((CheckBox)gridViewRow.FindControl("cbDelete")).Checked == true)
            {
                string ID = ((Label)gridViewRow.FindControl("labelID")).ToString();
                int n = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
                lstE.Add(n);
            }
      }

      this.Accountant = Data.Instance.NHibernateSession.Load<Accountant>(lstE);
      Data.Instance.NHibernateSession.Delete(this.Accountant);
      Data.Instance.NHibernateSession.Flush();
}
```

The problem is resolved with a foreach loop for my list items:

```
foreach (int nn in lstE)
{
  //delete function
}
```

Comment: Try code as i have provided u in answer and no need to create list..

Answer (score 1):

On Button click just put this code and remove `AutoPostBack="true"                    oncheckedchanged="cbDelete_CheckedChanged"` From your gridview checkbox

```
//remove checked rows
        protected void btn_removeall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow gr in grid.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox cc = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("cbDelete");
                    if (cc.Checked == true)
                    {                  
                        string id = grid.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Values["ID"].ToString();        
                        //
                        //call your delete function here
                        //
                    }
                }           
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are loading your gridview from within Page_Load, which is fine. but in your case you would need to make sure your gridview loading code looks like this:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //gridview loading code
}
```

this prevents your gridview from being reloaded (and losing which boxes are checked) when you click your delete button

Comment: well, i get the values of the checked items returned in a list. But it looks like that Nhibernate doesnt work well with loading and deleting lists. this.Accountant = Data.Instance.NHibernateSession.Load<ClassLibSales.Accountant>(list) <--;